# Unable to read values from contract deployed in hyperledger blockchain

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger

I have set up the hyperledger blockchain locally. I run the hyperledger bc service within the docker container. I am able to bring up the node successfully, able to deploy and write to bc using a [sample contract](https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/learn-chaincode/blob/master/finished/chaincode_finished.go).

But couldnt read back the data from the block chain. Below is the error message bc throws. Can anyone pls guide what's wrong here ?

```
    [ibc-js] Deploy Chaincode - Complete
{"query":{},"invoke":{},"details":{"deployed_name":"c123c14a65a511ee79e2a41b23726f473478d002064c01c3ce035cffa1229af083d73f1db220fc2f267b9ae31d66ce2e10113548e7abdf8812986ac3c5770a9c","func":{"invoke":["init","write"],"query":["read"]},"git_url":"https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/learn-chaincode/finished","options":{"quiet":true,"timeout":60000,"tls":false},"peers":[{"name":"vp0-vp0...:49155","api_host":"127.0.0.1","api_port":49155,"id":"vp0","tls":false}],"timestamp":1470146338831,"users":[],"unzip_dir":"learn-chaincode-master/finished","version":"github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim","zip_url":"https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/learn-chaincode/archive/master.zip"}}
sdk has deployed code and waited
[ibc-js] write  - success: { jsonrpc: '2.0',
  result:
   { status: 'OK',
     message: '8b340e92-f96f-41f6-9b15-6ccb23304360' },
  id: 1470146405598 }
write response: { jsonrpc: '2.0',
  result:
   { status: 'OK',
     message: '8b340e92-f96f-41f6-9b15-6ccb23304360' },
  id: 1470146405598 }
    [ibc-js] read  - success: { jsonrpc: '2.0',
      error:
       { code: -32003,
         message: 'Query failure',
         data: 'Error when querying chaincode: Error:Failed to launch chaincode spec(Could not get deployment transaction for c123c14a65a511ee79e2xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxe7abdf8812986ac3c5770a9c - LedgerError - ResourceNotFound: ledger: resource not found)' },
      id: 1470146405668 }
    read response: null { name: 'query() resp error',
      code: 400,
      details:
       { code: -32003,
         message: 'Query failure',
         data: 'Error when querying chaincode: Error:Failed to launch chaincode spec(Could not get deployment transaction for c123c14a65a511ee79e2xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxe7abdf8812986ac3c5770a9c - LedgerError - ResourceNotFound: ledger: resource not found)' } }
```

I have used IBM Blockchain JS for interacting w/ the go contract.
Below is the node js code

```
// Step 1 ==================================
var Ibc1 = require('ibm-blockchain-js');
var ibc = new Ibc1(/*logger*/);             //you can pass a logger such as winston here - optional
var chaincode = {};


// ==================================
// configure ibc-js sdk
// ==================================
var options =   {
    network:{
        peers:   [{
            "api_host": "127.0.0.1",
            "api_port": 49155,
            //"api_port_tls": 49157,
            "id": "vp4"
        }],
        users: null,
        options: {quiet: true, tls:false, maxRetry: 1}
    },
    chaincode:{
        zip_url: 'https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/learn-chaincode/archive/master.zip',
        unzip_dir: 'learn-chaincode-master/finished',    
        git_url: 'https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/learn-chaincode/finished'

    }
};

// Step 2 ==================================
ibc.load(options, cb_ready);

// Step 3 ==================================
function cb_ready(err, cc){                             //response has chaincode functions

chaincode = cc;

   console.log(JSON.stringify(cc));

   chaincode.deploy('init', ['Hi hyperledger'], null, cb_deployed);


// Step 5 ==================================
function cb_deployed(){

    console.log(JSON.stringify(chaincode));
    console.log('sdk has deployed code and waited');

    console.log('******** Writing to chaincode Now **********');
    chaincode.invoke.write(["mykey","Hi Ledger Systems"],function(err,data){
    console.log('write response:', data);

   readData();


});
}



function readData()
{

console.log('\n\n**** Waiting 7 seconds before reading **** \n\n');
setTimeout(function () {
  console.log('\n\n**** Start reading **** \n\n');

  chaincode.invoke.read(["mykey"],function(err,data){
   console.log('read response:', data);

 });
}, 7000)
}


  }
```

Comment: Your link to the chaincode is broken, pointing towards a non-existant page. Please post the chaincode - or at least the relevant query method - in the question. I suspect this might be because the chaincode encountered an error in the query method, which forced the chaincode to stop running, but cannot verify that without access to the chaincode.

Comment: Here is the CC deployed name @DavisBroda `c123c14a65a511ee79e2a41b23726f473478d002064c01c3ce035cffa1229af083d73f1db220fc2f267b9ae31d66ce2e10113548e7abdf8812986ac3c5770a9c` chaincode.invoke.write(["mykey","Sample Data Inserted"] chaincode.query.read(["mykey"] \n I am using [github.com/IBM-Blockchain/ibm-blockchain-js]IBM Block Chain JS node module to deploy, write and query the chaincode. Pls note that I am running the instance locally you might not be able to connect to my CC.

Comment: Please edit the relevant code into the question, instead of putting it into a comment. It's very difficult to read when it's in a comment. Also, I was asking for the chaincode, not the js. The chaincode should be written in Go, and should look something like this [example](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/examples/chaincode/go/chaincode_example02/chaincode_example02.go). Please post the Query method from your chaincode, as well as the input you're submitting. Also, I do not need to connect to your chaincode, I need to see the source code.

Comment: Hi @DavisBroda I have modified the question. Added nodejs code for interacting with contract. Hyperlink given for deployed Go Contract.

Comment: First thing's first, you're doing `chaincode.invoke.read` rather than `chaincode.query.read`. Given that read is a query method, that might cause problems. But it's probably not causing this particular issue. From what I'm reading, it looks like the deployment transaction failed. Are you absolutely sure it deployed/wrote correctly? If so, how do you know? Did you query the blocks directly and see what happened? Maybe try submitting deploying/writing/reading from postman so that you can isolate whether this is a cc issue, or a javascript issue.

Comment: Yes, agree it should be chaincode.query.read, I was using invoke to see if read function is getting called.  I have modified the question to include the response from blockchain about deployment and write Success message. But, I could see this message in the console. `ledger] CommitTxBatch -> DEBU 0f3 There were some erroneous transactions. We need to send a 'TX rejected' message here.` Also, When i do 127.0.0.1:5000/chain, i could see there is an increase the block length when i do write/invoke.

Comment: Your console logs seem odd. It should be outputting the stringified chaincode object twice (once from ready, and once from deployed). additionally the *****Writing to chaincode now ***** line is missing from the console. Also, please add a console.log statement so that I can distinguish between the stringified send from ready, and from deployed. I suspect that somehow a null chaincode is being passed to cb_deployed(), and this would help confirm that.

Comment: The generic error message ResourceNotFound from v0.5/v0.6 has been replaced by more descriptive errors in v1.0.  Please try on v1.0 and report results.